# SQL Server Error Log Path Returns null in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the SQL Server error log path in PowerShell for further operations which will be performed.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") 
$sqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('serverName')
$logPath=$sqlServer.ErrorLogPath
```

This code works fine in SQL Server 2012 & above environment perfectly. However in SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2, the `$logpath` is always `null`.

Please let me know if any module needs to be added.

Comment: What is there in $sqlServer when you are running the code in 2k8 and 2k8r2?

Comment: Both would create an SQL related object without any errors. However in 2KR2, the error log path & few other parameter seems to be null. @RanadipDutta

Comment: That gave your answer. If the underlying object, in your case i.e. ErrorLogPath, is not holding any value in 2k8; so your logpath is variable is not picking anything. What is that you are trying to achieve now ?

Comment: Yes its not picking up anything for ErrorLogPath and that is exactly my issue. The script works fine in 2k12 environment but not 2kr2. Basically I need to get the log path to perform checks post SQL restarts. @RanadipDutta

Comment: in 2k8, that object is not at all present. If you want to capture any error then you get the entire bunch in `$error`.

Comment: ok thank you for this update.

Comment: What version of SMO are you using?  With SMO version 10 on a server running Windows 2008 and SQL 2008R2 your code returns the ErrorLogPath correctly.  I don't have a SQL 2008 server to test against but it also works for SQL 2005 and SQL 2000 servers from the same Windows host.